# Dual boot Yoga 2 pro

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I want to dual boot Ubuntu on my Yoga 2 pro but Device manager will only let me shrink my main volume by 9 GB and i need 75 GB. I have 115 GB of free space and I'm not sure what to do now?

Comment: By device manager, do you mean in Windows? The Ubuntu Live CD image will let you partition things the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the amount of shrinkable volume by trying the following:

1. Install Auslogics Disk Defrag (http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag/). It will give you critical information on why your volume's shrinkable size is limited. If you notice that the immovable files towards the end of your volume are not Master File Table files (MFTs) then you are in luck and can continue below.
2. Disable System Restore.
3. Disable the pagefile. Often, pagefile.sys is the unmovable file that prevents you from being able to further shrink your volume. You can do this by going to Advanced System Settings in Control Panel, click on Performance > Advanced > Change > No Paging File. In Windows 10, you must click on the "Set" button to make the changes take effect.
4. Disable Hibernation Mode by opening an elevated command prompt (i.e. right click command prompt and run as administrator) and typing "powercfg -h off"
5. Open disk cleanup and delete any unnecessary files.

Once you do this, restart your computer and launch the disk defragmenting tool you downloaded in step 1. Defragment your active Windows drive you wish to shrink. Restart your computer once again.

Now, launch disk utilities and try resizing the partition again. Hopefully, you should be able to shrink your drive further. I was able to shave off over 100GB from my 250GB SSD after I followed these steps. In my case, it was the pagefile.sys that was preventing my PC from shrinking the volume at first.

Note: once you have shrunk your volume to your liking, you can feel free to re-enable the items you might have had to disable earlier.

Good luck!

Source(s):
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/working-around-windows-vistas-shrink-volume-inadequacy-problems/